# Subscription from an Orion Context Broker to another Orion Context Broker doesn't work

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware

I have created a new Orion instance on fi-lab in order to connect it to a CEP instance managed with us too. The data, which is going to be stored on my Orion instance, has to be provided by the existent Orion Instance located on orion.lab.fi-ware.eu:1026

In order to have the data available in the new Orion instance, a subscription request is sent to the "principal" Orion instance. This subscription is an ONCHANGE subscription and the request is made with the appropiate header tokens to the URL http://orion.lab.fi-ware.eu:1026/NGSI10/subscribeContext

The request content is the following:

`{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "location:mytype",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "x:y:z"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [],
    "reference": "http://a.b.c.d:1026/",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "TimeInstant"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

When I make this request, the response is:

`<subscribeContextResponse>
    <subscribeResponse>
        <subscriptionId>53d7473d1860a3cb2359ff11</subscriptionId>
        <duration>P1M</duration>
    </subscribeResponse>
</subscribeContextResponse>`

But when I update the attribute 'TimeInstant' from the entity 'x:y:z' in the original Context Broker there is no changes on the similar entity in my Orion Instance. So there is no update request from the original Orion to my Orion.

I have accomplished this ONCHANGE subscription from my Orion Context Broker instance to the Proton engine, only by changing the url reference attribute from the request to the CEP url which receive events.

The CB entity works with a security group which enables access from 22, 8080 and 1026 ports.

I think the problem is in the URL reference attribute, I have tried with the a.b.c.d:1026/NGSI10/updateContext too and I have the same problem.

Could someone give me any ideas about my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [federation section in the Orion User Manual](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/federation/index.html):

> Note that the URL used in the reference has to be
>   "/v1/notifyContext".

So I think that using `"reference": "http://a.b.c.d:1026/v1/notifyContext"` would solve the problem.